# Different output from round function of oracle and Pandas data frame

Tags: oracle, pandas

Round function in oracle and Pandas are giving different values.
Is there a way to make them same apart from writing custom function.

```
select round(23.685,2) from dual; ---23.69
```

Pandas round function code :

```
Sample = {'Value': [23.685]}
df = pd.DataFrame(Sample, columns= ['Value'])
df.round(2)  --23.68
```

Comment: Python uses [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). I'm guessing Oracle just rounds half up...?

Comment: Please let me know if the link in dupe doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @ChrisA/ @anky_91 Thanks for the link I got some clue from these links.Can now figure out something and will answer.